# Getting an "invalid_client_id" error after setting all the OAuth data properly

Tags: rest-api, client-id

I created a new connected application, configured all the OAuth settings as shown in the guides.
I did this:
I created a new application.
I added full access scope.
I changed the IP policy.
And yet every time I try to log in I get an error:

```
{
     "error": "invalid_client_id",
     "error_description": "client identifier invalid"
}
```

I make a connection request in the following way:

```
POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: test.salesforce.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 273

grant_type=password&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_SECERT&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD
```

Does anyone have a solution or direction of thinking where the problem could come from?

I have been waiting for more than 24 hours and it still returns the same error,
In case I send a lot of requests per second, one for 15 requests returns successfully with a token..

post Scriptum. In another account I have in Salesforce I did the same process and it worked great for me! Now in the new account exactly the same and I am shown these errors..

Comment: When I change the login address to my personal salesforce address, the login succeeds.